# Unable to display the image path correctly from php array

Tags: php, html, cakephp-2.0

Im trying to display the html like  echo $contentsArray[0]; in php, however the image is not displayed.
since, the img path is displayed like `"<?=POST_IMG?>post/item/mypost/post_1.png"` instead of 
`"img/PostImg/post/item/mypost/post_1.png"`. How should I fix this problem.

```
define('POST_IMG', 'img/PostImg/');

$item1 = '<a href="#" target="_blank"> <div class="left">
              <img src="<?=POST_IMG?>post/item/mypost/post_1.png">
            </div></a>';

$contentsArray = array($item1, ...More
```

Comment: Its a string to php so do like this `<img src="'.POST_IMG.'post/item/mypost/post_1.png">`. You just have to concatinate the variable in your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have problem with the concatenation inside your code.
you can refer following code,

**Note :** it is better to avoid use of short-hand php tag

```
 define('POST_IMG', 'img/PostImg/');

$contentsArray = array('<a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="left">
           <img src= "'.POST_IMG.'post/item/mypost/post_1.png">
        </div>
</a>', ...More
```